# Find time duration between two pulse of same signal

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

i want to find time duration between two pulse of same signal. That's mean time duration between falling edge of first pulse and rising edge of second signal. Here, i'm using Arduino Uno board. 
Here, Image show my two pulse of same signal. i want to find time t.

[image]

I want some logic or arduino code.

Comment: this is not a coding service. try to solve it yourself. if you have problems with it, describe what you have tried, what you expect to happen and what happens instead. provide your arduino code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check function pulseIn()
It will solve your problem.
Note: Just put LOW as parameter.